How to serve two Laravel projects on the same IP address without subdirectories?
I have two Laravel projects on my Ubuntu server. Right now, they are accessible via:
https://ipaddress/script1
https://ipaddress/script2

But I want to access them directly like:
https://ipaddress/ (Project 1)
https://ipaddress/another-path/ (Project 2)

\<VirtualHost \*:80\>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/project1/public"
ServerName ipaddress
\</VirtualHost\>

\<VirtualHost \*:80\>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/project2/public"
ServerName ipaddress/another-path/
\</VirtualHost\>

What I have tried:
Edited the 000-default.conf file.
Ran a2ensite and restarted Apache.
When I open https://ipaddress/, it only loads Project 1, and the second route doesn't work.
